# data not getting passed on clicking submit in material-ui react login form

Tags: reactjs

I've created a login form in reactjs using material ui but my data aren't getting passed when I click on submit button. Right now, I tried to console log the password and email from var body but I'm getting undefined. I want to know where I'm doing wrong. Even the email and password in useState are not being highlighted so most probably they're not being used I think

```
const performLogin = async (event, email, password) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var body = {
    password: password,
    email: email
  };
  console.log(body);
};

export default function Demo() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");          //email and password are not highlighted so that means they're not being used anywhere
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form
          className={classes.form}
          noValidate
          onSubmit={(event, email, password) =>
            performLogin(event, email, password)
          }
        >
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
            onChange={email => setEmail(email)}
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            onChange={password => setPassword(password)}
          />

          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things wrong on your code:

```js
  onSubmit = {(event, email, password) =>
    performLogin(event, email, password)
  }
```

This **onSubmit** call, is formally okay, but redundant: you have this email and password already stored on a hook so you should not need to pass it to `performLogin` function, the problem is that your onChange calls aren't updating the values:

```js
onChange={email => setEmail(email)}
```

So, first, we'll solve this **onChange** function, it should look like this:

```js
 onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
```

Now the hooks are properly updated and now you can call them anywhere inside your function, onSubmit can be as simple as this:

```js
  onSubmit={performLogin}
```

and then you can see the values just calling the hooks:

```js
  performLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('A email was submitted: ' + email);
    alert('A pass was submitted: ' + password);
  }
```

This will help you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-faraday-kblzo

Answer (score 0):

onChnage gives the event as parameter and not the value itself

```
onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
```